# C# Windows Service Not Compressing Folder Correctly

Tags: c#, windows-services, compression, directory

Im currently building a Windows service that will be used to create backups of logs. Currently, the logs are stored at the path `E:\Logs` and intent is to copy  the contents, timestamp their new folder and compress it. After this, you should have `E:\Logs` and `E:\Logs_[Timestamp].zip`. The zip will be moved to C:\Backups\ for later processing. Currently, I am using the following to try and zip the log folder:

```
var logDirectory = "E://Logs";
var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
var zippedFolder = logDirectory + "_" + timeStamp + ".zip"; 

System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(logDirectory, zippedFolder);
```

While this appears to create a zip folder, I get the error `Windows cannot open the folder. The Compressed (zipped) Folder E:\Logs_201805161035.zip is invalid.`

To address any troubleshooting issues, the service is running with an AD account that has a sufficient permission level to perform administrative tasks. Another thing to consider is that the service kicks off when its FileSystemWatcher detects a new zip folder in the path `C:\Aggregate`. Since there are many zip folders that are added to `C:\Aggregate` at once, the FileSystemWatcher creates a new Task for each zip found. You can see how this works in the following:

```
    private void FileFoundInDrops(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {          
        var aggregatePath = new DirectoryInfo("C://Aggregate"); 

        if (e.FullPath.Contains(".zip"))
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var logDirectory = "E://Logs";
                    var timeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmm");
                    var zippedFolder = logDirectory + "_" + timeStamp + ".zip"; 
                    ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(logDirectory, zippedFolder);                       
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Log.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + " - ERROR: " + ex);
                }
            });

            task.Dispose();
        }           
    }
```

How can I get around the error I am receiving? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just a guess: since your `FileSystemWatcher` event handler is called for each zip file and multiple zip files are created at once in the Aggregate folder. Your problem can be caused by conflicting `Logs_yyyyMMddHHmm.zip` file names. (same time, same minute)

Comment: I followed your advice and used the format aforementioned format but measured down to the second that the zip was detected. Now, the backups have different names but they still prompt with the same error.

Comment: @alxsj : The service is working (one file at a time) if I remove the line Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ... Is there any reason this wouldn't work in a FileSystemWatcher?